# jssor shifting main div center

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

I'm brand new to jssor, so... I am having a strange issue in Chrome where my page center shifts about 5 pixels to the left when I load the page with the slideshow. If you toggle between the classroom page and any other, you can see what I'm talking about. Then, if you mouse over either navigation arrow, it shifts back to center! Thank you for the great slider and any suggestions.

http://carolinamountainmontessori.com/classroom.html

Comment: I don't see the issue you describe in chrome, also tested in Firefox and IE9 without issues.

Comment: I should clarify, this is Chrome 35.0.1916.153 on a MAC. Safari works fine; it's just Chrome where the page consistently re-centers 5 pixels left on load...